# But due to within a sentence?

Tags: grammar

My friend used "but due to" in this sentence: "She wants to work harder but due to her health condition is not allowed to do so". Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: It is perfectly normal English though, personally, I would enclose "due to her health condition" in commas since it can be seen as parenthetical. This would give: _"She wants to work harder but, due to her health condition, is not allowed to do so". _

Comment: Why do you think "but due to" is incorrect? Standards three years ago may have been different, but this question is actually just proof-reading. We have [help](/help/on-topic) on "Is it correct?" questions: scroll down the Help page to "How can I ask about checking my text?"

Answer (score 1):

**due to (someone or something)**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/due+to+(someone+or+something)) an idiom

> 1. As a result of something.

As in:

> The baseball game was well underway, **but due to** impending lightening
>   it was cancelled.

Your friend's grammar is correct.